# <DataGrid><DataTemplate><ComboBox> name does not exist

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to set up a combo box with in my DataGrid and I am not allowed to set the ItemSource of the combo box (in my in my .xaml.cs  code) because I keep receiving this error "The name 'cboChangeRequestStatus' does not exist in the current context. Don't understand why I can set this in other variations of DataGrid but cannot when I use this set

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusCode}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox   SelectedValue="{Binding Status, Mode= TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="StatusId"
                        DisplayMemberPath="StatusCode"
                        Name="cboChangeRequestStatus"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that easily, and you shouldn't do that.

Directly from MSDN: 
Styles and templates in WPF provide the ability to reuse and reapply content in a straightforward way. However, styles and templates might also include elements with XAML names defined at the template level. That same template might be used multiple times in a page. For this reason, styles and templates both define their own XAML namescopes, independent of whatever location in an object tree where the style or template is applied.

See: [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx#Namescopes_in_Styles_and_Templates)

If you have a Class like:

```
public class Test
{
  public ObservableCollection<Status> StatusCollection { get; set; }
  public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Than you could use it like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusCollection}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Or consider creating a StaticResource for the collection if the collection is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say.... you are setting the ViewModel as the DataContext of the Window in which you have you DataGrid... then..

## XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusCodes,
                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                              Mode=FineAncestor
                                             AncetorType={x:type Window}}}"
                     SelectedValuePath="StatusId"
                     DisplayMemberPath="StatusCode"
                     Name="cboChangeRequestStatus"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```